# Minecraft server double port forwarding

Tags: router, wireless-router, port-forwarding, minecraft, netgear-router

We have a fiber optics internet connection to a default modem(/router?) in our home. The connection through that box is weak so we bought a stronger Netgear router as well as a Netgear network adapter to boost the wifi signal.

The problem is that I can't seem to get a Minecraft server working. I'm guessing the problem lies with port forwarding through both routers. I ran servers before when I had just one router and it worked fine.

Router setup:

[image: Router setup]

I've tried forwarding ports on both routers though unsure what IP to use I've just used them all to no avail, I'm honestly not even sure which of these IPs to use in the server properties file. And the second router only allows for device IPs to be used in the port forwarding, so all I could do for that was forward port 25565 on 10.0.0.6.

Netgear ports:

[image: Netgear Ports]

ITI ports:

[image: ITI Ports]

It was so simple with the one router, but now I'm at a loss of what to do to make this work. I'm not too tech savvy and used to just following tutorials.

If someone has any advice so my friends and I can play that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you disable routing in the fiber optic gateway?

Comment: So you only bought the second router because you needed better Wi-Fi coverage, right? Is it connected to the first router using a wired connection? If that’s the case, the network can be restructured to do away with the double NAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by experimenting further with my router settings.

First I disabled DHCP on my ITI router which disabled my internet and I only 'fixed' it by rebooting the router entirely. Then I found an option in my Netgear router configuration to change it to an 'Access Point' I enabled this and it completely disabled port forwarding and other such options in the router settings and removed the 10.0.0. IPs.

It seems to all be working on my ITI IP now, I hope this may help others encountering the same issue.